# Storing a billion polygons in quad-tree

Tags: c++, spatial

I need to store 1 billion spatial polygons (specified using their Minimum Bounding Rectangles) in a quad-tree. For doing so, I wrote the following code. However, it turns out that for 1 billion points the code is running very slowly. Is there some way by which I may improve the code so that it may run a bit faster. If yes, then can someone please help with the same

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct MBR
{
    double xRight, xLeft, yBottom, yTop;
    MBR *zero,*first,*second,*third;
    unsigned level=0;
    vector<unsigned> result; //contains the resulting intersecting spatial ids
};
bool intersects(MBR& spatialId,MBR& mbr) 
{
    if (mbr.yBottom > spatialId.yTop || mbr.yTop < spatialId.yBottom) return false;
    if (mbr.xLeft > spatialId.xRight || mbr.xRight < spatialId.xLeft) return false;        
    return true;    
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool contains(MBR& spatialId,MBR& mbr) 
{
    if (mbr.yBottom > spatialId.yBottom || mbr.yTop < spatialId.yTop) return false;
    if (mbr.xLeft > spatialId.xLeft || mbr.xRight < spatialId.xRight) return false;
    return true;    
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool touches(MBR& spatialId,MBR& mbr) 
{
    if (    (mbr.yBottom >= spatialId.yBottom + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() && 
            mbr.yBottom <= spatialId.yBottom - std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()) ||
            (mbr.yTop >= spatialId.yTop + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() &&
            mbr.yTop <= spatialId.yTop - std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()))
            return true;
    if (    (mbr.xLeft >= spatialId.xLeft + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() &&
            mbr.xLeft <= spatialId.xLeft - std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()) ||
            (mbr.xRight >= spatialId.xRight + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() &&
            mbr.xRight <= spatialId.xRight - std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()))
            return true;    
    return false;    
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MBR MBR1,MBR2,MBR3,MBR4;
vector<unsigned> spatialIds; //contain 1 billion spatial identifiers which are intersected with MBR1, MBR2, MBR3, MBR4
//MBR1, MBR2, MBR3, MBR4 are again specified using their Minimum Bounding Rectangles    
stack<MBR**> stackQuadTree;
MBR *root=new MBR();
(*root).yBottom=-90; (*root).yTop=90;
(*root).xLeft=-180; (*root).xRight=180;
(*root).level=0;
stackQuadTree.push(&root);

while(!stackQuadTree.empty())
{
    MBR** node=&(*stackQuadTree.front());
    if((*node)->level==50)
        break;

    (*node)->zero=new MBR(); (*node)->first=new MBR(); (*node)->second=new MBR(); (*node)->third=new MBR();
    (*node)->zero->yBottom=(*node)->yBottom; (*node)->zero->yTop=((*node)->yBottom+(*node)->yTop)/2;
    (*node)->zero->xLeft=(*node)->xLeft; (*node)->zero->xRight=((*node)->xLeft+(*node)->xRight)/2;                        
    (*node)->zero->level=(*node)->level+1;

    (*node)->first->yBottom=((*node)->yBottom+(*node)->yTop)/2; (*node)->first->yTop=(*node)->yTop; 
    (*node)->first->xLeft=(*node)->xLeft; (*node)->first->xRight=((*node)->xLeft+(*node)->xRight)/2;          
    (*node)->first->level=(*node)->level+1;

    (*node)->second->yBottom=(*node)->yBottom; (*node)->second->yTop=((*node)->yBottom+(*node)->yTop)/2;
    (*node)->second->xLeft=((*node)->xLeft+(*node)->xRight)/2; (*node)->second->xRight=(*node)->xRight;        
    (*node)->second->level=(*node)->level+1;

    (*node)->third->yBottom=((*node)->yBottom+(*node)->yTop)/2; (*node)->third->yTop=(*node)->yTop;
    (*node)->third->xLeft=((*node)->xLeft+(*node)->xRight)/2; (*node)->third->xRight=(*node)->xRight;                        
    (*node)->third->level=(*node)->level+1;

    MBR* node=*stackQuadTree.top();
    stackQuadTree.pop();        
    for(vector<MBR>::iterator itSpatialId=spatialIds.begin(),lSpatialId=spatialIds.end();itSpatialId!=lSpatialId;++itSpatialId)
    {
        if(intersects((*itSpatialId),&(*node)->zero)||contains((*itSpatialId),&(*node)->zero)||touches((*itSpatialId),&(*node)->zero))
        {
            (*node)->zero->result.push_back((*itSpatialId));
            stackQuadTree.push(*(*node)->zero);
        }

        if(intersects((*itSpatialId),&(*node)->first)||contains((*itSpatialId),&(*node)->first)||touches((*itSpatialId),&(*node)->first))
        {
            (*node)->first->result.push_back((*itSpatialId));
            stackQuadTree.push(*(*node)->first);
        }                    

        if(intersects((*itSpatialId),&(*node)->second)||contains((*itSpatialId),&(*node)->second)||touches((*itSpatialId),&(*node)->second))
        {
            (*node)->second->result.push_back((*itSpatialId));
            stackQuadTree.push(*(*node)->second);
        }   

        if(intersects((*itSpatialId),&(*node)->third)||contains((*itSpatialId),&(*node)->third)||touches((*itSpatialId),&(*node)->third))
        {
            (*node)->third->result.push_back((*itSpatialId));
            stackQuadTree.push(*(*node)->third);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you store 1 Billion elements. Are you sure you need to load all of them ? A good practice is to load only the elements you are really using.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Unfortunately I need to load all 1 billion polygons and store them in my quad-tree :(

Comment: you copy your `MBR` a ton: `intersects(MBR spatialId,MBR mbr)` and similar functions should use references `intersects(const MBR &spatialId, const MBR &mbr)` since otherwise you're always allocating and copying `vector`s

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Thank you very much. I am a little novice at these spatial data structures, can you please explain a little as to how can I allocate nearby leaves in bunches?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Thank you very much. I tried using references, but still my overhead is too much.

Comment: Time to do some profiling? If you know how many nodes you will need, simply allocate an array of them in the beginning (`MBR* nodes = new MBR[n]`) and use pointers to this array. Getting rid of billion allocs will definitely help. What is the usual size of the `MBR::result` vectors?

Comment: Also, rewrite `intersects(...)`, `contains(...)`, and `touches(...)` to eliminate the conditionals. As in: `return (!(mbr.yBottom > spatialId.yTop || mbr.yTop < spatialId.yBottom) && !(mbr.xLeft > spatialId.xRight || mbr.xRight < spatialId.xLeft));`. Feel free to use intermediate `bool` variables to make it more legible, however eliminating a lot of the branching should help speed things up.

Comment: @Jannat Arora: Can you actually post some code that will compile? I see a number of issues, such as calling `front()` on std::stack or `vector<MBR>::iterator itSpatialId=spatialIds.begin()` where `spatialIds` is `vector<unsigned>`...

Answer (score 18):

Since the requirement is to handle 10<sup>9</sup> records, and even with the most compact representation each record is 16 Bytes (`4 * sizeof(float)`), we would need 16 GiB just to keep those in memory. As we want to use the bounding boxes of polygons for indexing, it is possible for each bounding box to belong to multiple quadrants. If there is a lot of relatively large polygons or many overlaps, the memory requirements of the whole quadtree could significantly increase. That suggests an iterative approach to building the quadtree, where we use files to store the lists of bounding boxes matching each node, as well as the node information for the entire tree.

---

## Quadtree Library

### Rectangle Representation

We use rectangles to represent two things:

- The bounding box of the polygon (i.e. our input data).
- The bounding box of a quadrant (a node in the quadtree).

We also need to perform some operations on rectangles, such as subdividing them into quadrants, or finding whether a pair of rectangles intersects. Let's write a simple class to encapsulate this.

**rectangle.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

template<typename T = float>
struct rectangle_t
{
    typedef typename T value_type;

    rectangle_t() : left(0.0f), top(0.0f), right(0.0f), bottom(0.0f) {}
    rectangle_t(value_type x1, value_type y1, value_type x2, value_type y2)
        : left(x1), top(y1), right(x2), bottom(y2)
    {
    }

    bool intersects(rectangle_t<T> const& other) const;
    bool contains(rectangle_t<T> const& other) const;
    bool touches(rectangle_t<T> const& other) const;
    rectangle_t<T> quadrant(uint32_t n) const;

    value_type left, top, right, bottom;
};

template<typename T>
inline bool rectangle_t<T>::intersects(rectangle_t<T> const& other) const
{
    return !((left > other.right)
        || (right < other.left)
        || (top > other.bottom)
        || (bottom < other.top));
}

template<typename T>
inline bool rectangle_t<T>::contains(rectangle_t<T> const& other) const
{
    return !((left >= other.left)
        || (right <= other.right)
        || (top >= other.top)
        || (bottom <= other.bottom));
}

template<typename T>
inline bool rectangle_t<T>::touches(rectangle_t<T> const& other) const
{
    return ((left == other.right)
        || (right == other.left)
        || (top == other.bottom)
        || (bottom == other.top));
}

template<typename T>
inline rectangle_t<T> rectangle_t<T>::quadrant(uint32_t n) const
{
    value_type const center_x((left + right) / 2);
    value_type const center_y((top + bottom) / 2);
    switch (n & 0x03) {
    case 0: return rectangle_t<T>(left, top, center_x, center_y);
    case 1: return rectangle_t<T>(center_x, top, right, center_y);
    case 2: return rectangle_t<T>(left, center_y, center_x, bottom);
    case 3: return rectangle_t<T>(center_x, center_y, right, bottom);
    }
    return *this; // Can't happen since we mask n
}

typedef rectangle_t<float> rectangle;
```

Note: While we also provide methods `contains()` and `touches()`, we don't really need them -- if rectangle A contains rectangle B, then the two also intersect. Similarly, if two rectangles have a pair of edges that overlap, they are also considered as intersecting.

---

### Rectangle Serialization

Next step is to develop a simple method of storing the rectangles in a file. We can use simple binary files, with layout that correspond to how the objects are represented in the memory.

[image: Rectangle Layout]

The file contains a single sequence of objects, no headers or anything else.

[image: Rectangle File Layout]

Since we wish to process the data in blocks, we implement simple *reader* and *writer* classes providing this functionality.

**rectangle_file.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "rectangle.hpp"
#include "config.hpp"

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<rectangle> rectangle_vec;

class rectangle_writer
{
public:
    rectangle_writer(std::string const& file_name);
    rectangle_writer(rectangle_writer const&) = delete;

    void write_block(rectangle_vec const& block);

    uint64_t count() const { return count_; }

private:
    std::ofstream f_;
    uint64_t count_;
};

class rectangle_reader
{
public:
    rectangle_reader(std::string const& file_name);
    rectangle_reader(rectangle_reader const&) = delete;

    void read_block(rectangle_vec& block, uint64_t n = BLOCK_SIZE);

    uint64_t count() const { return count_; }
    uint64_t total_count() const { return total_count_; }
    uint64_t remaining_count() const { return total_count_ - count_; }

private:
    std::ifstream f_;
    uint64_t count_;
    uint64_t total_count_;
};
```

---

**rectangle_file.cpp**

```
#include "rectangle_file.hpp"

#include <algorithm>

rectangle_writer::rectangle_writer(std::string const& file_name)
    : f_(file_name, std::ios_base::binary)
    , count_(0)
{
    if (!f_) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to open index file.");
    }
}

void rectangle_writer::write_block(rectangle_vec const& block)
{
    f_.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&block[0])
        , block.size() * sizeof(rectangle));
    count_ += static_cast<uint32_t>(block.size());
    if (!f_) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Read error.");
    }
}

rectangle_reader::rectangle_reader(std::string const& file_name)
    : f_(file_name, std::ios_base::binary)
    , count_(0)
{
    f_.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    total_count_ = static_cast<uint32_t>(f_.tellg() / sizeof(rectangle));
    f_.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
}

void rectangle_reader::read_block(rectangle_vec& block, uint64_t n)
{
    uint64_t to_read(std::min(remaining_count(), n));
    block.resize(to_read);
    if (to_read) {
        f_.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&block[0])
            , to_read * sizeof(rectangle));
        count_ += to_read;
        if (!f_) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Write error.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Quadtree Representation

Due to the large number of nodes we are likely to work with, we keep all the nodes in an array and instead of pointers use node indices to represent the hierarchy. Index of a node is determined by its position in the array, so we don't need to store that explicitly.

We use a compact structure (`node_info`) to represent the relevant node information:

- Rectangle defining the bounding box of the quadrant.
- Array of 4 indices of the child nodes. (We use 32bit indices, limiting us to ~4 billion nodes)

The list of matching rectangles for each node is stored in a data file, named based on the node index (`node_XXXXXXXX.dat`).

#### Node Flyweight

In order to encapsulate the representation of the quadtree, and expose a familiar interface for manipulating it, we create a flyweight class `node`, holding a reference to the `quadtree`, the index of the node, and current level in the tree (16 Bytes). This class provides all the functionality necessary to build and use the quadtree:

- Reading and writing the bounding box.
- Reading and writing the lists of matching rectangles.
- Access to child nodes, node index, current level, ...
- Adding child nodes

**quadtree.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "rectangle.hpp"
#include "rectangle_file.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class quadtree
{
public:
    class node
    {
    public:
        rectangle& bounds();
        rectangle const& bounds() const;

        node child(uint32_t i) const;

        rectangle_reader reader() const;
        rectangle_writer writer() const;

        std::string rectangle_file_name() const;

        void add_child_nodes() const;

        bool is_leaf_node() const;

        uint32_t index() const;
        uint32_t level() const;

    private:
        friend class quadtree;
        node(quadtree& tree, uint32_t index, uint32_t level);

        quadtree& tree_;
        uint32_t index_;
        uint32_t level_;
    };

public:
    enum {
        ROOT_NODE_INDEX = 0
        , QUADRANT_COUNT = 4
    };

    quadtree(quadtree&& other);
    ~quadtree();

    static quadtree create(std::string const& dir_name
        , rectangle const& bounds);
    static quadtree load(std::string const& dir_name);

    void save();

    node get_node(uint32_t i = ROOT_NODE_INDEX);
    uint32_t node_count() const;

private:
    quadtree(std::string const& dir_name);
    std::string index_file_name() const;

    uint32_t add_node(rectangle const& bounds);
    void add_child_nodes(uint32_t n);

private:
    struct node_info
    {
        node_info();
        explicit node_info(rectangle const& bounds);

        rectangle bounds;
        uint32_t child[4];
    };
    typedef std::vector<node_info> node_list;

    std::string dir_name_;
    node_list nodes_;
};

inline quadtree::node::node(quadtree& tree, uint32_t index, uint32_t level)
    : tree_(tree)
    , index_(index)
    , level_(level)
{
}

inline rectangle& quadtree::node::bounds()
{
    return tree_.nodes_[index_].bounds;
}

inline rectangle const& quadtree::node::bounds() const
{
    return tree_.nodes_[index_].bounds;
}

inline quadtree::node quadtree::node::child(uint32_t i) const
{
    return node(tree_, tree_.nodes_[index_].child[i], level_ + 1);
}

inline bool quadtree::node::is_leaf_node() const
{
    return !((tree_.nodes_[index_].child[0])
        || (tree_.nodes_[index_].child[1])
        || (tree_.nodes_[index_].child[2])
        || (tree_.nodes_[index_].child[3]));
}

inline uint32_t quadtree::node::index() const
{
    return index_;
}

inline uint32_t quadtree::node::level() const
{
    return level_;
}
```

---

### Quadtree Serialization

The layout on disk again corresponds to how the objects are represented in memory.

[image: Node Layout]

The node file is a simple binary file containing single sequence of objects:

[image: Node File Layout]

---

For illustration, this is how a 3 level quadtree (root + 2 levels of children) with 1000 rectangles appears on disk:

[image: Quadtree with 3 levels and 1000 rectangles]

---

### Configuration

**config.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#define BLOCK_SIZE (1024 * 8)

#define QUADTREE_LOGGING 0
#define WORKQUEUE_LOGGING 0
#define PROGRESS_LOGGING 1
```

---

## Processing

We base our processing on the following observations:

- A tree with only the root node is still a valid tree.
- We can subdivide any valid tree to get a deeper tree with more detailed categorization.

### Quadtree Initialization

The initial step is to create the simplest valid quadtree possible: one with only the root node, containing all the bounding boxes.

Since I didn't have any data I could use, I wrote a simple generator that creates a configurable number of random rectangles and uses them to initialize the tree.

**gen_rnd_tree.cpp**

```
#include "rectangle.hpp"
#include "rectangle_file.hpp"
#include "quadtree.hpp"
#include "config.hpp"

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <direct.h>
#endif

void generate_random(uint32_t n, quadtree& qt)
{
    rectangle_writer writer(qt.get_node().writer());

    std::vector<rectangle> buffer;
    buffer.reserve(BLOCK_SIZE);

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<rectangle::value_type> dis_x(-179.5f, 179.5f);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<rectangle::value_type> dis_y(-89.5f, 89.5f);
    std::exponential_distribution<rectangle::value_type> dis_wh(1.0f);

    for (uint32_t i(0); i < n; ++i) {
        rectangle::value_type x(dis_x(gen));
        rectangle::value_type y(dis_y(gen));
        rectangle::value_type half_w(std::min(dis_wh(gen), 10.0f) * 0.05f);
        rectangle::value_type half_h(std::min(dis_wh(gen), 10.0f) * 0.05f);
        buffer.emplace_back(x - half_w, y - half_h, x + half_w, y + half_h);

        if (buffer.size() >= BLOCK_SIZE) {
            writer.write_block(buffer);
            buffer.clear();
#if(PROGRESS_LOGGING)
            std::cout << ".";
#endif
        }
    }

    if (!buffer.empty()) {
        writer.write_block(buffer);
    }
#if(PROGRESS_LOGGING)
    std::cout << ".\n";
#endif
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::microseconds;

    if (argc != 2) return -1;

    std::string const TREE_DIR("tree");

#if defined(_WIN32)
    _mkdir(TREE_DIR.c_str());
#else 
    mkdir(TREE_DIR.c_str(), 0777);
#endif

    uint32_t const N_POLYGONS(atoi(argv[1]));

    std::cout << "Polygon count = " << N_POLYGONS << "\n";
    std::cout << "Polygon size = " << sizeof(rectangle) << " B\n";
    std::cout << "Total size = " << N_POLYGONS * sizeof(rectangle) << " B\n";

    std::cout << "\nGenerating...\n";

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    quadtree qt(quadtree::create("tree", rectangle(-180,-90,180,90)));

    generate_random(N_POLYGONS, qt);

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "\n";

    double dt1_us(static_cast<double>(duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count()));
    std::cout << "Generate: " << (dt1_us / 1000.0) << " ms\n";
    std::cout << "\nDone.\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

### Quadtree Subdivision

Function `subdivide(quadtree& qt,...)` performs a depth-first traversal of the tree using a stack. We could do a breadth-first traversal with a queue, but the queue would grow very large once we get deep enough in the tree.

We repeatedly consume nodes from the top of the stack, attempt to subdivide them, and push their child nodes on the stack.

Function `subdivide(quadtree::node const& qtn, ...)` makes the decisions whether to subdivide given node, and prepares the parameters for `copy_elements(...)`. Once the node is subdivided, and all the matching rectangles have been moved to child nodes, we clear the rectangle file for the given node.

Function `copy_elements(...)` reads the list of matching rectangles from the parent node, and copies them to all the child nodes whose bounding boxes they intersect.

```
#include "rectangle.hpp"
#include "rectangle_file.hpp"
#include "quadtree.hpp"

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::microseconds;

void copy_elements(rectangle_reader& reader, quadtree::node child_node[4])
{
    rectangle target[quadtree::QUADRANT_COUNT] {
         child_node[0].bounds()
        , child_node[1].bounds()
        , child_node[2].bounds()
        , child_node[3].bounds()
    };

    rectangle_writer writer[quadtree::QUADRANT_COUNT] {
        child_node[0].writer()
        , child_node[1].writer()
        , child_node[2].writer()
        , child_node[3].writer()
    };

    rectangle_vec buffer_in;
    buffer_in.reserve(BLOCK_SIZE);
    rectangle_vec buffer_out[quadtree::QUADRANT_COUNT];
    for (auto& buffer : buffer_out) {
        buffer.reserve(BLOCK_SIZE);
    }

#if(PROGRESS_LOGGING)
    for (; reader.remaining_count(); std::cout << ".") {
#else
    for (; reader.remaining_count();) {
#endif
        reader.read_block(buffer_in, BLOCK_SIZE);

        for (auto const& rect : buffer_in) {
            for (uint32_t i(0); i < quadtree::QUADRANT_COUNT; ++i) {
                if (target[i].intersects(rect)) {
                    buffer_out[i].push_back(rect);
                }
            }
        }

        for (uint32_t i(0); i < quadtree::QUADRANT_COUNT; ++i) {
            if (!buffer_out[i].empty()) {
                writer[i].write_block(buffer_out[i]);
                buffer_out[i].clear();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Return true if we should subdivide further, false otherwise
bool subdivide(quadtree::node const& qtn, uint32_t max_depth, uint32_t max_leaf_size)
{
    bool at_max_depth(qtn.level() >= max_depth);
    std::cout << (at_max_depth ? "Skipping" : "Subdividing")
        << " node #" << qtn.index() << " @ level " << qtn.level() << ".\n";
    if (at_max_depth) {
        return false;
    } else {
        // Make sure reader goes out of scope before writer is created.
        rectangle_reader reader(qtn.reader());
        if (qtn.is_leaf_node()) {
            if (reader.total_count() <= max_leaf_size) {
                std::cout << "Leaf node (" << reader.total_count() << ").\n";
                return false;
            }
            qtn.add_child_nodes();
        } else if (!reader.total_count()) {
            std::cout << "Branch node.\n";
            return (qtn.level() < max_depth);
        }

        quadtree::node child_nodes[4] {
            qtn.child(0)
            , qtn.child(1)
            , qtn.child(2)
            , qtn.child(3)
        };

        high_resolution_clock::time_point t1(high_resolution_clock::now());

        copy_elements(reader, child_nodes);

        high_resolution_clock::time_point t2(high_resolution_clock::now());
        double dt_us(static_cast<double>(duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count()));

        std::cout << ". (" << reader.count() << ") " << (dt_us / 1000.0) << " ms\n";
    }

    rectangle_writer writer(qtn.writer()); // Clean the file

    std::cout << "Branch node.\n";
    return (qtn.level() < max_depth);
}

void subdivide(quadtree& qt, uint32_t max_depth, uint32_t max_leaf_size)
{
    std::stack<quadtree::node> work;
    work.emplace(qt.get_node());
    std::size_t max_queue_size(work.size());

    for (; !work.empty();) {
        quadtree::node node(work.top());
        work.pop();

        if (subdivide(node, max_depth, max_leaf_size)) {
            for (uint32_t i(0); i < quadtree::QUADRANT_COUNT; ++i) {
                work.emplace(node.child(i));
            }
        }
        max_queue_size = std::max(max_queue_size, work.size());
#if(WORKQUEUE_LOGGING)
        std::cout << "* Work queue " << work.size() << " (" << max_queue_size << ").\n";
#endif
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uint32_t const MAX_DEPTH(atoi((argc >= 2) ? argv[1] : "2"));
    uint32_t const MAX_LEAF_SIZE(atoi((argc >= 3) ? argv[2] : "100"));

    std::cout << "Loading...\n";

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1(high_resolution_clock::now());

    quadtree qt(quadtree::load("tree"));

    if (qt.node_count() < 1) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid tree.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Building tree (max_depth=" << MAX_DEPTH
        << ", max_leaf_size=" << MAX_LEAF_SIZE << ")...\n";

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2(high_resolution_clock::now());

    subdivide(qt, MAX_DEPTH, MAX_LEAF_SIZE);

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t3(high_resolution_clock::now());

    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "Tree completed (" << qt.node_count() << " nodes).\n\n";

    double dt1_us(static_cast<double>(duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count()));
    double dt2_us(static_cast<double>(duration_cast<microseconds>(t3 - t2).count()));
    std::cout << "Load: " << (dt1_us / 1000.0) << " ms\n";
    std::cout << "Process: " << (dt2_us / 1000.0) << " ms\n";
    std::cout << "\nDone.\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

## Usage

- `gen_rnd_tree <count>` -- Generate tree with *count* rectangles in root node.
- `build_tree <max_depth> <max_node_size>` -- Subdivide nodes with more than *max_node_size* rectangles, up to depth *max_depth* (root is at depth 0).

### Sample Output

```
Polygon count = 1000
Polygon size = 16 B
Total size = 16000 B

Generating...
.

Generate: 0 ms

Done.

Loading...
Building tree (max_depth=5, max_leaf_size=100)...
Subdividing node #0 @ level 0.
.. (1000) 15.624 ms
Branch node.
Subdividing node #4 @ level 1.
.. (288) 15.625 ms
Branch node.
Subdividing node #8 @ level 2.
Leaf node (71).
Subdividing node #7 @ level 2.
Leaf node (59).
Subdividing node #6 @ level 2.
Leaf node (81).
Subdividing node #5 @ level 2.
Leaf node (77).
Subdividing node #3 @ level 1.
.. (212) 0 ms
Branch node.
Subdividing node #12 @ level 2.
Leaf node (46).
Subdividing node #11 @ level 2.
Leaf node (55).
Subdividing node #10 @ level 2.
Leaf node (55).
Subdividing node #9 @ level 2.
Leaf node (58).
Subdividing node #2 @ level 1.
.. (260) 15.626 ms
Branch node.
Subdividing node #16 @ level 2.
Leaf node (68).
Subdividing node #15 @ level 2.
Leaf node (69).
Subdividing node #14 @ level 2.
Leaf node (71).
Subdividing node #13 @ level 2.
Leaf node (53).
Subdividing node #1 @ level 1.
.. (240) 0 ms
Branch node.
Subdividing node #20 @ level 2.
Leaf node (68).
Subdividing node #19 @ level 2.
Leaf node (60).
Subdividing node #18 @ level 2.
Leaf node (62).
Subdividing node #17 @ level 2.
Leaf node (50).

Tree completed (21 nodes).

Load: 0 ms
Process: 109.377 ms

Done.
```

---

When tried with 10<sup>8</sup> rectangles, `BLOCK_SIZE` of 64k records, it took about 45 seconds to build a tree with `max_depth` of 6. That already gives nodes with approx. 10<sup>5</sup> items that could be easily handled with in-memory algorithm.

The program only used few MiB of RAM for the whole process.

---

## Further Improvements

- Error checking, unit tests (I wouldn't be able to fit the code here).
- Add metadata to the rectangle file, so you can find what polygons they match. I would keep the size of the record a multiple of 16 Bytes (alignment).
- Parallelization

  - Mutex to synchronize the `quadtree`, mutex to synchronize the `stack`, thread pool to run the `for (; !work.empty();) { ...` loop.
  - Since we only push child nodes after they were subdivided, each thread will always work on an isolated section of the tree.
- Hybrid approach

  - Disk I/O becomes the bottleneck in this kind of processing. Once we get to small enough nodes (say 10<sup>5</sup> - 10<sup>6</sup> entries), we can handle the data conveniently in-memory.
  - Use the node list from this algorithm as a lookup to load the "small" in-memory quadtrees. Implement caching mechanism, to keep the most recently looked up "small" quadtrees available.
- Vectorization (could perhaps speed up matching large numbers of rectangles).

Comment: Not even one reply... Dude it's so great from you to write all this down!

Comment: This is such a rich answer. Started a bounty and will award it to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

log2(1 billion) is approximately 30

In order to reduce your operations count, consider a data structure that more rapidly gets to the right neighborhood.

For example, if you know that your objects are located within a grid that is 10km x 10km, consider breaking it down into a 10x10 grid (1kmx1km)
Then, any object that falls within a particular grid can immediately jump to 1% of the objects (assuming they are evenly distributed).

Obviously, you can have a recursive structure, but you really don't need more than one or two 10x10 splits.  Why not try a top level, where each subgrid is a quadtree?

I also notice you have an odd construction:

```
mbr.yTop >= spatialId.yTop + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()
```

I think you can simplify this to:

```
spatialId.yTop < mbr.yTop
```

That is kind of the definition of your floating point resolution, isn't it?  If I'm right, that should speed up your code a lot but that's just a constant factor.

```
class Grid {
private:
  stackQuadTree qt[100]; // 10x10 array of quadtrees
public:
  Grid(double xmin, double xmax, double ymin, double ymax) {
    // store your 10x10 grid in the grid object
    gridSizeX = 1/10 of the size of grid in the x
    gridSizeY = 1/10 of the size of grid in the y
  }

  stackQuadTree& findGrid(MBR& mbr) {
    int i = (mbr.xLeft - xmin) / gridSizeX;
    int j = (mbr.yTop - ymin) / gridSizeY;
    return qt[i*10+j];
  }

  void add(MBR& mbr) {
    // add the right quadtree and add the object in
  }
};
```

Comment: Sorry I am little novice. How can I create each sub-grid as a quad-tree

Comment: I added a skeleton for what a top-level grid could look like, hardcoded to 10x10.  You could, of course, pick a different number like 16x16

Comment: Do you need full double precision accuracy?  If you reduce to float you can drop your memory by a factor of 2 and that will help a lot too.

Comment: Thanks. I dont need double, float would work for me. Thanks a lot for this

Answer (score 2):

Well, several leads:

1. You can speed up your code without changing the structure
2. You can speed up your code changing the structure in order to be multi thread and so you gonna use the several cores of your computer.
3. The best solution is to apply 1 and then 2.

1)

a- `sizeof(MBR)` should give something like 76 Bytes + vector dyn memory space , so all objects copied in `intersects`, `touches` and `contains` should be removed. Uses `bool myfunc(const MBR & spatialId, const MBR & mbr)` instead for the 3 methods, `myfunc={intersects, touches , contains}.`

b-
Store `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` in a const variable. The compiler gonna like it !

2)

Multithreading the process is mainly to paralellise the inner `for` loop.
A simple way to do this is to use [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP).

Try to surround the `for` loop with `#pragma` directives, something like that :

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(vector<MBR>::iterator itSpatialId=spatialIds.begin(),lSpatialId=spatialIds.end();itSpatialId!=lSpatialId;++itSpatialId)
{
   // ....
}
#pragma omp barrier
```

but this will not be enough because some shared data will be accessed concurrently (leading to crashes). So you must use lock/mutex/atomics in order to protect `stackQuadTree` and `MBR::result` on `push_back`'s

Comment: @JannatArora "Can not" as in "don't know how" or "not allowed to", or perhaps some other reason?